# Get request only returns _id of nested elements and not full elements from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mean

I am building my first mean stack app and have trouble configuring all routes and getting back the data I want.

I have two models.

Course :

```
var CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    code: String,
    name: String,
    courseContentGrade: Number,
    courseTeachingGrade: Number,
    courseAverage: Number,
    reviews: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, refs: 'review'}]
});
```

and Review :

```
var ReviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    contentReview: String,
    teachingReview: String,
    contentGrade: Number,
    teachingGrade: Number,
    average: Number,
    professor: String,
    trimester: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['T1', 'T2', 'T3']
    },
    day: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi', 'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi']
    },
    time: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['9h-12h', '13h15-16h15', '16h30-19h30']
    },
    round: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['1', '2', '3']
    },
    bet: Number,
    year: Number,
    upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
    author: String,
    course: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Course'}
});
```

I have set up routes to be able to get all courses and get all reviews of a specific course. When I use curl to get the reviews of a specific course (`localhost:3000/courses{course.id}`) I only get back [] but when I use curl to get all courses, (`localhost:3000/courses/{course.id}/reviews`) I get back all courses and in each courses I have : `"reviews":["review.id","review2.id"]`. and when I curl a specific review (`localhost:3000/reviews/{review.id}`) I get the review object.

So far I have configured these routes :

```
router.get('/courses', function(req, res, next) {
  Course.find(function(err, courses){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(courses);
  });
});

router.get('/reviews/:review', function (req, res) {
    res.json(req.review);
});

router.get('/courses/:course', function (req, res) {
    res.json(req.course);
});

router.get('/courses/:course/reviews', function (req, res){
    res.json(req.course.reviews);
});
```

And I use these param :

```
router.param('review', function (req, res, next, id) {
    var query = Review.findById(id);

    query.exec(function (err, review){
        if(err) { return next(err);}
        if(!review) {return next(new Error('can\'t find review'));}

        req.review = review;
        return next();
    });
});

router.param('course', function (req, res, next, id) {
    var query = Course.findById(id).populate('reviews');

    query.exec(function (err, course){
        if(err) { return next(err);}
        if(!course) {return next(new Error('can\'t find course'));}

        req.course = course;
        return next();
    });
});
```

EDIT :

The solution to that question is the populate function (see below), and on top of that I had used 'review' as the name of my model when referencing it in course instead of 'Review' (notice the R/r) and when I had an s at ref in course, I had no error raised on that point....no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the below route to include the populate function:

```
Router.get('/courses', function(req, res, next) {
    Course.find().populate('reviews').exec(function(err, courses){
        if(err){ return next(err); }

        res.json(courses);
    });
});
```

Written on mobile so apologies for any typos!

Comment: hi, thanks for your time (again!). When I use that solution, it doesn't solve my problem and the review's id disappear from the courses when i just use the /courses route. I'll look into that populate function, it's already been a problem for me.

Comment: I don't understand, I looked into the code of other projects and they ALL use populate successfully. The difference I notice between my project and other's is the schema definition :

I have : `var CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 code: String,
 name: String,
 courseContentGrade: Number,
 courseTeachingGrade: Number,
 courseAverage: Number,
 reviews: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, refs: 'review'}]
});` While they have no s at `ref`. But when I take it off I get an error

Comment: Unbelievable. I had named the review model 'Review' but referenced 'review' in my course schema. When using the s at ref, I had no problem, when I didn't use it, I had an error and didn't notice de R/r at Review. I have no idea why the s prevented the error...